# CarrierWave not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, carrierwave

Ruby version 2.1.5 and rails 4.1.8.

So i am working on an app, using devise for authentication process. i need to add an avatar option where user can upload an image and for this i am using carrierwave. i follow all the instructions given [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-use-carrierwave-with-devise), but avatar is not saving anywhere.

here is my **avatar_uploader.rb**

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    storage :file
    def store_dir    
        "public/uploads"
    end
end
```

here is my model **user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
     :validatable, :confirmable, :timeoutable

attr_accessor :login, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar

validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true

validate :email

def email_required?
    false
end

def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
     conditions = warden_conditions.dup
     if login = conditions.delete(:login)
         where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
         where(conditions).first
    end
 end
end
```

here is my **index.html.erb**

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :username %>
<% if Own_settings.minimum_username_length %>
<em>(<%= Own_settings.minimum_username_length %> characters minimum)</em>
<% end %><br />
<%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true%>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %>
<em>(Optional)</em><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password %>
<% if @minimum_password_length %>
<em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
<% end %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div>
<%= f.file_field :avatar %><br />
<%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %><br />
</div>  

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
</div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

here is my **edit.html.erb**

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, multipart: :true }) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div>
<% if current_user.avatar.url.present? %>
  <%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url.to_s %>
  <%= f.label :remove_avatar %>
  <%= f.check_box :remove_avatar %>
<% end %>
<%= f.file_field :avatar %>
<%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :username %>
<% if Own_settings.minimum_username_length %>
<em>(<%= Own_settings.minimum_username_length %> characters minimum)</em>
<% end %><br />
<%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true%>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
<div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %>
<div/>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
<%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Update" %>
</div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

[This is where error come][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulH9j.png when i try to call edit page.

Answer (score 0):

Before avatar uploading there is no avatar assigned to user. First you must check is there any avatar. Your condition should look like this 
`current_user.avatar.presence?` not `current_user.avatar.url.presence?`

Comment: okay you are right, but the problem is not here, my avatar is not getting save anywhere when i upload them on signup page

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your avartar_uploader.rb file and how you are not including RMagick or MiniMagick support. Also, your storage direction won't work so I included the store_dir that works for me.

You need to add/fix the following code.

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarriierWave:RMagick
  storage :file

  def store_dir    
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

You can also use Cloudinary for file storage online. It works great with CarrierWave. Cloudinary is a cloud-based service that provides an end-to-end image management solution including uploads, storage, administration, image manipulation, and delivery.

Here is the documentation http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_carrierwave